# Get DEP Setting

Tags: c#, dep

I need to determine if Windows DEP is disabled, set to essential windows programs and services or all programs except those I select.

I've searched for a way of doing this but haven't had any success. Is there a way of doing this? Developing in C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public enum DepSystemPolicyType
{
    AlwaysOff = 0,
    AlwaysOn,
    OptIn,
    OptOut
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern int GetSystemDEPPolicy();

public static void ValidateDepPolicy()
{
    int policy = GetSystemDEPPolicy();
    //here you can evaluate the return value
    //against the enum DepSystemPolicyType
}
```

MSDN documentation: [GetSystemDEPPolicy function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Bryan, out of interest...do you have a code library with code snips like this in it, or do you recall this and tap it out by hand?

Comment: @DanHall I had to implement something similar in an installer which I happened to be working on when I saw your question. I just grabbed the code snippet.